# DialogFlow parameter reprompt after validation

Tags: dialogflow-es, chatbot

I have an intent where bot is asking for date to the user. The users might say `today`, `last week`, `last monday` etc.
If the user is saying things like `last week` or `last month` (basically things which cannot be converted into an exact date), then bot should prompt again `please enter exact date to proceed`.

**Case 1: taking @sys.date**

I have marked this entity as required and set prompt `please enter the date`, now every time user is saying last week, it is not being detected by `@sys.date` and user is getting same prompt again and again.

**Case 2: taking @sys.date-time**

If i take `@sys.date-time` i am able to get all kind of inputs.
If user said last week, last months etc then I will get `startDate` in parameter value, if user said today, there will be direct value in parameter.
This can be processed in `webhook for slotfilling` as well, we can set parameter value to `null` and invoke same intent again by I am not able to figure out **how to set different prompt**

```
params = req['queryResult']['parameters']
date = params['date']
if 'startDate' in date:
    print('inside startDate')
    res = json.dumps({
        'followupEventInput' : {
            'name' : 'e_date',
            "parameters": {
                "date": '',                 
                }
            }
        })
```

By above code, intent is triggered again but prompt is again same which we have set in DialogFlow console.

I had to take `@sys.date` as entity because it offers `date.recent` option which is suitable for my use case, by taking `@sys.date-time` or `@sys.date-period` the date DialogFlow is catching is not correct. For example if today is tuesday and user said last monday then Dialogflow will catch monday of last week, not the most recent monday. And there are many cases like this if we are not taking `date.recent`

Comment: dialogFlow works very odd sometimes in date/time cases. some times works very well and some time detects dates with wrong patterns. So I end up with showing a confirmation message from my bot to user that all is fine and proceed the process further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend to create a other intent having training phrases like: last week or last month. Then have this response prompt the user to be more specific on a date.

Comment: i kind of did the same, created fallback intent and gave training phrases `last week`, `last month` etc