# entities vs follow-up intent

Tags: dialogflow-es

Suppose i want to make a pizza ordering DialogFlow agent. To order a pizza we need 3 things: `size`, `type` and `toppings`.

If we want to go with follow-up intents approach rather than using entities then there will be so many combinations in which user might provide the information.

1: i want a pizza -> no info
2: i want small pizza -> size
3: i want small cheese pizza -> size and type
4: i want small cheese pizza with olives -> size, type and toppings
5: i want small pizza with olives -> size and toppings
...
and so on

**How to solve this problem?**
There will be so many combinations if we have more entities (2^n combinations)

**Note 1:** cannot take entities and slotfilling option as there are so many problems if we go down that road, like re-prompts loop, validation etc.
Is there any better solution?

**Note 2:** If we use entities, mark them required, and set prompts then many times if it does not get desired input from user it get stuck in re-prompt loop, i.e it keeps asking user same (or random) prompt for same entity. In my use case, it is bad for user experience. If we use follow-up intents instead, then we can set fallback intents for all those intents which solved this problem. (please note that this is just example of the use case)

[image]

[This is another example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52575649/dialogflow-parameter-reprompt-after-validation) of why I used follow-up intents, it solved my date capturing problem as well. I took `@sys.date.recent` and set a fallback intent to capture inputs like `last week, last month` etc, this was not possible using slots.

Comment: Can you update your question with how you expect the conversation to go in each of these cases? (ie - When do you ask for more information and how do you expect that conversation to sound like?)

Comment: @Prisoner updated the question with more details. about the conversation, all the parameters are required to do further processing, so we need to collect all the information. user can give them in any order we should be able to collect all info correctly.

Answer (score 1):

First, remember that Intents should reflect *what the user says*, not necessarily what you are doing.

On the surface, it isn't clear why slot filling (either with fulfillment or using built-in prompts) won't meet your needs. Since you've indicated that all three bits of information are necessary (size, type, and toppings), you can mark them as such in your phrases and Dialogflow will prompt for the missing information until it gets everything.

You almost certainly do *not* want to use Followup Intents. These are good when you always have a specific response that you send that will always have a very narrow set of replies from the user, but are very poor if the response from your action will prompt the user to reply in many different ways.

Instead, I would use a related concept: Contexts. (At least if you're not going to use slot filling.) When you ask the question of what they want, set a Context so you know they are. Then have one or more Intents that have this as an Input Context that accept the various things the user might say. Your webhook should see if you have the information you need and, if not, prompt them what else you're looking for. At the end, prompt for a confirmation, but they may say something that adjusts the order.

Comment: thanks for the response, slot filling and built in prompts were causing issue in validation and was getting stuck in re-prompt loop if user does not provide correct value for slot.
and i meant intents with context in the question, not the actual follow-up intents. sorry for the confusion.